# How to call PHPCap external package in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, redcap

I need to use the below package in Laravel 5.5 it's an external package.

https://github.com/iuredcap/phpcap

I download zip from above the GitHub URL and phpcap directory added in Laravel 5.5 vendor folder.

and use below code and in my controller.

```
use \IU\PHPCap\RedCapProject;
```

OR

```
use IU\PHPCap\RedCapProject;
```

and Call below function in my action

```
$project = new RedCapProject($apiUrl, $apiToken);
```

But every time given below error.

```
Class 'IU\PHPCap\RedCapProject' not found
```

Comment: use composer to require packages, that will generate your autoload to know the newly added package, see how in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509367/how-to-require-package-into-laravel-project-with-composer)

Comment: try to run "composer dump-autoload" to generate the autoload